# How to fix #ref in a vlookup formula after deleting cell in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ref

The formula I am trying to use is: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,M:P,3,0),"")
i am trying to figure out how to fix "a3" from going to #ref. The data in column A gets deleted but i would like the formula to still reference whatever is in column A regardless of it being deleted.

the same is happening with this formula: =AND(COUNTIF(A:A,A3),COUNTIF(M:M,A3))

Comment: Delete the cell contents, not the cell itself.

Comment: Or change `A3` to `INDEX(A:A,3)`. This does assume that you never delete the entire column A.

Comment: @BigBen would this work if I drag the entire formula down? so far it looks like it is still referencing A:A,3 and nothing else. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Perhaps `INDEX(A:A,ROW())` if you mean to refer to the cell in column A on the same row.

Comment: @BigBen thank you so much! it worked! Is it possible for you to explain how INDEX(A:A,ROW()) works? trying to see how I can integrate this into other reports I have.